# C# OpenXML documentation understand animations in PowerPoint

Tags: c#, animation, powerpoint, openxml

I try to get animations from PowerPoint presentations, using `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll`. Which I tried is:

`using (PresentationDocument presentationDocument = PresentationDocument.Open(pptPath, true))
            {
                var slidepart = presentationDocument.PresentationPart.SlideParts.First();
                var slide = slidepart.Slide;
                var xml = slide.OuterXml;
            }`

to get the first slide's XML. But I can't understand the entire XML structure and specific the animations tags.

Is there any good documentations about that, or some samples?

**EDIT:** I found next documentations and I started to read them:
[Open XML SDK in GitHub](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-content/blob/master/en-us/OpenXMLCon/articles/d4ef73a6-888a-4476-9e21-4df76782127f.md)
[officeopenxml.com](http://officeopenxml.com/anatomyofOOXML-pptx.php)

Thank you!

Comment: Probably the best documentation about the format itself is part 4 of the specification, available at http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm.

Comment: Thank you, @DirkVollmar!